# File watch WebStorm не туда компилирует файл .css

Tags: node.js, scss, webstorm

У меня есть файл SCSS(в папке SCSS) нужно скомпилировать и сохранить в папке CSS (CSS файл).
А у меня он создает папку с именем файла и складывает туда файл.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

SCSS компилирует `node-sass` с помощью `file watch` в WebStorm.
Нужно изменить конфиг компилирования.
Он пока такой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
<sub>(источник: [pastexen.com](http://pastexen.com/i/jKXFz2xWZA.jpg))</sub>

`Arguments` такой:

> --output-style=expanded  $FileName$ -o $ProjectFileDir$/css/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css

Answer (score 3):

опция `-o` используется для того, чтобы задать директорию, в которой создается файл. См. https://github.com/sass/node-sass, **Command Line Interface**:

```
Usage

node-sass [options] <input> [output]
Or:
cat <input> | node-sass > output

Example:

node-sass src/style.scss dest/style.css

Options:

    -w, --watch                Watch a directory or file
    -r, --recursive            Recursively watch directories or files
    -o, --output               Output directory
```

если Вы хотите создать файл`$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css`  в папке `$ProjectFileDir$/css`, достаточно указать `$ProjectFileDir$/css` в качестве  `Output directory`:

`Arguments: $FileName$ -o $ProjectFileDir$/css`